# Erro no Visual Studio

Tags: c, visual-studio

**EDIT: Problema resolvido, após mudar boa parte do código, não só nas funções aqui citadas, o erro parou de ocorrer.**

Estou recebendo esse erro e não tenho a menor idéia de o que pode estar causando ele, nunca havia presenciado esse erro antes. Alguma dica sobre a causa do erro?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Após clicar em Break o código que aparece é esse:

```
_CRTIMP PFLS_GETVALUE_FUNCTION __cdecl __set_flsgetvalue()
{
#ifdef _M_IX86
    PFLS_GETVALUE_FUNCTION flsGetValue = FLS_GETVALUE;
    if (!flsGetValue)
    {
        flsGetValue = DecodePointer(gpFlsGetValue);
        TlsSetValue(__getvalueindex, flsGetValue);
    }
    return flsGetValue;
#else  /* _M_IX86 */
    return NULL;
#endif  /* _M_IX86 */
}
```

O erro ocorre ao chegar nessa parte do código:

```
void imprime_vertices(head* h)
{

    int i, n;
    n = (h[0]).grau;

    for(i = 1; i <=n; i++){
        printf("%d %d %d\n", h[i].vertice[0], h[i].vertice[1], h[i].vertice[2]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Quando o erro ocorre e você pressiona "Break", qual é a informação na janela de pilha de chamadas (call stack)? Ela pode dar uma boa indicação de onde o erro se encontra. Se tiver dúvidas sobre o código no local indicado, não esqueça de editar a pergunta pra incluí-lo, senão fica bem difícil de alguém ajudar. :)

Comment: Atualizado. @LuizVieira

Comment: Ok. :) Desculpe se a pergunta parecer muito básica, mas você chegou a depurar a sua função `imprime_vertices` pra ver se (1) o ponteiro `h` está devidamente alocado e (2) o grau do vértice está condizente com o número de arestas? Aliás, por que pra cada aresta no vértice você imprime três valores? Sem conhecer a sua estrutura de dados, eu imaginaria que se forem fixos deveriam ser dois identificadores (do vértice atual e do outro ao qual a aresta conecta).

Comment: Depurei sim, o erro é no Visual Studio mesmo, uma vez que compilando e executando no terminal o código roda normalmente.

Comment: Não acho que o erro é "no Visual Studio". Talvez o erro esteja acontecendo e o seu programa termina sem você notar. O VS só está te alertando porque nele você executa em modo de depuração. Dá uma olhada na resposta existente. Ela tem uma dica importante relacionada com o que eu estava comentando.

Comment: Esta pergunta parece ser descontextualizada porque é sobre um erro de codificação muito específico do autor, que dificilmente será útil para outras pessoas na comunidade (ao menos no formato atual da pergunta).

Answer (score 2):

Usando o `i` como indice dum array, isto parece errado

```
for(i = 1; i <=n; i++)
// h[0] nao acedido
// tentativa de aceder a h[n], que nao existe???
```

Os arrays, em C, vao do indice `0` ao indice `N-1`. A forma canónica de escrever um ciclo que percorre todos os elementos dum array é

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
```

Comment: Muito bem notado. :)